# How to use Query String in Gitlab REST API

Tags: gitlab, query-string, gitlab-api

I found Gitlab API from here [GetProjectMembers](https://docs.gitlab.com/13.12/ee/api/members.html#list-all-members-of-a-group-or-project-including-inherited-members)

It says we can use query string in API.

```
GET /projects/:id/members/all
```

```
Attribute   Type    Required    Description
query      string         no    A query string to search for members
```

So my question is how to query it like 'access_level=50' or some how.

I am a really fresh man for this and thank you in advance.

Comment: AFAIK (though I'm still digging), the (fuzzy?) query filter for `.../members/[all]` applies only to the `name`, `username` and `email` attributes.

Answer (score 0):

I found sth like this

```
/project_members?sort=access_level_desc
```

and this is a Compromise method